# Trying to understand §3.3.1/4

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, linkage

Apparently from §3.3.1/4, this snippet doesn't compile because it contains two different entities with the same name `A` in the global namespace, `extern int A;` and `static int A = 101;`. That is, one has external and the other has internal linkage.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91aab5a4a37ad8dd)

```
#include <iostream>
extern int A;
static int A = 101;
class A{};
int main()
{
    std::cout << A << '\n';
}
```

Why then, does this code compile?

```
#include <iostream>
static int A = 101;
extern int A;
class A{};
int main()
{
    std::cout << A << '\n';
}
```

**Edit**

I think the accepted answer for the question, of which this one is considered a dup, basically says that in the second snippet, variable `A` still has internal linkage, despite the `extern` declaration. But this is in disagreement with paragraph §3.5/4 that I mentioned below in a comment to @dyp.

§3.5/4:

> An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly
>   within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. All other namespaces
>   have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not been
>   given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing
>   namespace if it is the name of
>
> — a variable; or
>
> ...

**Edit 1:**

The OP uses §3.5/6 to justify his answer to the other question.

§3.5/6 (emphasis mine):

> The name of a function **declared in block scope** and the name of a
>   variable **declared by a block scope** extern declaration have
>   linkage. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage
>   having the same name and type, ignoring entities declared outside the
>   innermost enclosing namespace scope, **the block scope declaration**
>   declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous
>   declaration. If there is more than one such matching entity, the
>   program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the
>   **block scope** entity receives external linkage.

It's clear this answer doesn't apply to the snippets shown on my question, as the declarations of the variable `A` are **not** block scope declarations.

**Edit 2:**

[This issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1603) with "ready" status says that §7.1.1/7 should be deleted because it's false.

Comment: *"Why then, does this code compile?"* With which compiler+version?

Comment: The Standard doesn't require `extern` variables (at namespace scope) to have external linkage, as far as I can see. I think the second declaration "inherits" the linkage of the first declaration in the second example.

Comment: But then, why the first code doesn't compile?

Comment: I am not entirely certain about what the Standard says here. I think what happens is that in the first example, `A` in the first declaration is not found, and hence a name *with external linkage* is introduced. The `static` in `static int A;` however requires *internal linkage*, hence the error. In the second example, `A` in `extern int A;` finds the existing name with *internal* linkage, and somehow adopts the internal linkage.

Comment: Possibly related: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1603

Comment: I don't think this issue applies here. I'm not using unnamed namespaces and besides that, §3.3.1/4 is not mentioned in there.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil I cited that defect report since there are some known defects related to linkage and `extern`; the specification will most probably change here.

Comment: I don't like wielding my Mjölnir, but I agree with @remyabel It's a good question, but a duplicate.

Comment: That's what I think is a problem with SO. The question may be duplicate but AFAICT it still doesn't have a correct answer that is supported by the Standard, simply because §7.1.1/7 is false.

Answer (score 4):

The `extern` specifier *does not* require that the name has external linkage.

### The first example

`extern int A;` is a declaration of a name `A` with external linkage - but the external linkage is implied since it's a declaration at namespace scope (outside of an unnamed namespace).

`static int A`; declares a name with *internal linkage*.

The two declarations disagree about the linkage, hence the error.

### The second example

Here, we first declare `static int A;`, i.e. a name `A` with *internal linkage*.

The declaration `extern int A;` doesn't declare `A` with external linkage, it merely redeclares a name that is found via name lookup.

[dcl.stc]/7

> The linkages implied by successive declarations for a given entity
>   shall agree. That is, within a given scope, each declaration declaring
>   the same variable name or the same overloading of a function name
>   shall imply the same linkage. Each function in a given set of
>   overloaded functions can have a different linkage, however.
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> static char* f(); // f() has internal linkage
> char* f() // f() still has internal linkage
> { /* ... */ }
>
> char* g(); // g() has external linkage
> static char* g() // error: inconsistent linkage
> { /* ... */ }
>
> // [left out some examples with `inline`]
>
> static void n();
> inline void n(); // internal linkage
>
> static int a; // a has internal linkage
> int a; // error: two definitions
>
> static int b; // b has internal linkage
> extern int b; // b still has internal linkage
>
> int c; // c has external linkage
> static int c; // error: inconsistent linkage
>
> extern int d; // d has external linkage
> static int d; // error: inconsistent linkage
> ```
>
> -- *end example* ]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure *where* the Standard specifies that the `extern` declaration in the second example adopts the linkage of the first, though.

Comment: I think 3.5.6: `If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the same name and
type, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, the block scope declaration
declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration.`

Comment: `The declaration extern int A; doesn't give A internal linkage, it merely redeclares the name.` This doesn't seem to agree with §3.5/4: `An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace has
internal linkage. All other namespaces have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not
been given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing namespace if it is the name of — a variable;`

Comment: @remyabel The OP's example is not about block-scope variables.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Yes, I think there is something missing here about redeclarations. I think the examples I quoted in my answer state the intent.